# TCPClient is not closed, and instead waits for a client to close it

Tags: c#, server, tcpclient

i have few questions about programming a TcpListener.

First problem:

Once client is connected using browser, i see the request. it is all ok. but then i face the problem with writing. and client recieving that data. it basically never gets a reply from server. do i need that flush function ? how does it work ? and is there any others ways of doing it ?

Porblem number 2 which is even more weird. when i call client.close() client doesnt go anywhere. it is still there. browser is stillw ating for data. and when i kill connection in the browser, only then Tcp client gets closed and loop starts again.

```
namespace TestServer
{
    class Program
    {
       public static void Main()
        {
            TcpListener server;
            IPAddress addr = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
            server = new TcpListener(addr, 80);


            server.Start();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];


            while(true)
            {
                string data = null;
                Console.WriteLine("Awaiting for connections");
                TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();

                Console.WriteLine("Connected...");

                NetworkStream str = client.GetStream();

                int msgCounter;

                while ((msgCounter = str.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Processing stream...");

                    data += System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, msgCounter);
                    Console.WriteLine("Reciaved: {0}", System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, msgCounter));
                }


                byte[] response = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("200 OK");
                str.Write(response, 0, response.Length);

                str.Flush();

                client.Close();

                buffer = new byte[1024];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the debugger say?

Comment: no errors, nothing really.

Comment: But have you stepped through the implementation? Has it even reached the `client.Close() `call?

Comment: Are you sure your client code is correct? As does it listen for responses from the server?

Comment: @NewCallum the client is a browser

Comment: i used browser to send request to server. simple http GET. i did get that request. then  i attempt to responde to it. and nothing happens. when i close connection manually via browser only then code continues to execute.

Comment: Ok second while loop blocks it. looks like stream never ends!

Comment: "only then code continues to execute." --- what does it mean? How the debugger behaves when you step through your code?

Comment: Use wireshark to see if your data is being sent? Thats a good start

Comment: while ((msgCounter = str.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)  this line blocks it all! any suggestions on how to improve that one ?

Comment: There is no built-in TCP mechanism to signal that the client is not sending any more data. So you must do that on the application layer protocol level. In this case - you need to read the request, parse it and handle as per the HTTP standard. https://tools.ietf.org/html//rfc2616#section-5

Comment: `when i kill connection in the browser, only then Tcp client gets closed and loop starts again.` Because `TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();` is a blocking connection... It will not continue till you finish the code in the loop. So it is typically *serve clients one by one* code (additionally with bugs)

Answer (score 2):

TCP as a bi-directional transport layer protocol does not denote any concept of the "client is done sending request" signal.

What it means for developers is that such signaling must be defined in the application (or any other higher level) protocol layer.

In your case it is declared by HTTP itself in the https://tools.ietf.org/html//rfc2616#section-5

So if you intend to implement an HTTP server you must parse the HTTP request that has a determined way to identify the end of the request (see the link above).

To summarise: you need to know somehow you've read the request entirely and you may start processing it and generating/sending the response.

Comment: Thansk a lot bro. that saved my day. best wishes to you:)

Comment: @AntonStafeyev it's a good habit to mark an answer with a green checkmark (on the left right below the answer rating) if it answered your question.

Comment: Regairding the code in question, there are many other problems other than detecting the close as  stated in *title*

Comment: @L.B like what?

Comment: Like laking of threads (a blocking call `server.AcceptTcpClient`), assuming `str.Read` will return the complete string (think of multibyte chars) etc.

Comment: @L.B being single threaded for learning is fine, the data in HTTP is ASCII.

Comment: @L.B you don't need to read "the whole line" - they accumulate the request in the `data` string. Now they "just" need to implement `bool IsHTTPRequestComplete(string data)` and `break;` on it.

Comment: well i am aware of blocking calls, but i am just learning c#. first day today. i used nodejs for a while but it looks it is not as stable as it is. and documentetion lacks a lot of defenitions and it is very short. this why i decided to give c# a try.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to start with [a million times proven working MSDN example of TcpListener class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener(v=vs.110).aspx).  Additionally I can point to explicit wrong approach:

1. Do not recreate buffer, it is a waste of resources.
2. Do not use browser as a test client if you are working with TCP sockets. Any browser tries to correct somehow HTTP protocol errors and can do it in very unpredictable way. If you need HTTP level of debugging, use Fiddler, for lower levels - Microsoft Network Monitor, Wireshark of Netcat.
3. It could be useful to read some book about TCP/IP networking. Particularly, you will know, that there is not "close" operation or command for TCP connection by protocol definition, TcpClient just emulate it. Instead a peer can send "shutdown" to another one, it does mean it doesn't plan to send data anymore, but can read it.  Connection can be considered as closed only after both peers have sent their "shutdown" and received "shutdown" from each other.

Comment: "and potential leak of memory" --- I would not call it a "memory leak" though.

Comment: memory leak could appear if you use async operations and face exception, it is just a wrapper around WINSOCK, inside resources unmanageble

Comment: I saw it myself :)

Comment: It's a bug then and should be reported. PS: the downvote is not mine.

Comment: For the last 20 years I missed several chances to become famous. This is the one.

Comment: Well, I still don't see how #1 is relevant. The buffer is created outside of the socket, it is managed by the runtime and is a subject for garbage collection as soon as it goes out of scope. (and in the OPs code it is just create once).

Comment: Ok, let's assume you have convinced me. I can describe my case more detailed in chat, if you interested.